# pnpm postinstall ngcc doesn't run as should

Tags: angular, pnpm

within our ci pipeline, I try to use pnpm instead of npm as a package manager, but the `postinstall` script used to compile ivy incompatible libraries does not run as expected.

The console output shows that the postinstall script gets executed, but then the `pnpm install` process finishes without executing ngcc.

```
devDependencies:
+ @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.1001.7
+ @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr 0.1001.7
+ @angular/cli 10.1.7
+ @angular/compiler-cli 10.2.1
+ @angular/language-service 10.2.1
+ @ngxs/devtools-plugin 3.7.1
+ @nrwl/cli 10.4.4
+ @nrwl/cypress 10.3.1
+ @nrwl/jest 10.3.1
+ @nrwl/workspace 10.3.1
+ @types/jest 26.0.8
+ @types/leaflet 1.5.19
+ @types/node 14.0.27
+ codelyzer 5.2.2
+ cypress 4.12.1
+ cypress-localstorage-commands 1.3.0
+ dotenv 8.2.0
+ eslint 7.3.1
+ husky 4.3.5
+ jest 26.2.2
+ jest-preset-angular 8.3.1
+ lint-staged 10.5.3
+ ng-packagr 10.1.2
+ prettier 2.0.5
+ ts-jest 26.4.0
+ ts-node 8.10.2
+ tslint 6.1.3
+ typescript 4.0.5

> package@version postinstall /home/...
> ngcc --properties es2015
```

That's everything that happens. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to set the `shamefully-hoist` setting to true in an `.npmrc` file in the root of the project. If it doesn't help, open an issue in the pnpm repository or write to our discord chatroom

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? I am facing the same issue :)

Comment: No I'm sry, did not manage to get that working! :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Update the `ngcc` command in your `postinstall` script to include `--loglevel debug`.
   This will let you know what NGCC is doing, even if it doesn't find any entry-points to analyze (which is what is probably happening, due to the fact that PNPM structures node_modules in a way NGCC doesn't work with);
2. Create (or update) a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project to include the following:

   ```
   node-linker=hoisted
   ```

   This instructs PNPM to use a flat node_modules without symlinks ([more info](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker)). Don't worry, the speed of PNPM doesn't come solely from its isolated (symlinked) dependencies strategy. In my tests, hoisted vs. isolated are very similar time wise.
3. Delete the whole node_modules directory of your project and install it again with `pnpm install`.
   You should see NGCC's output (hopefully) telling you it found entry-points and detailing it's processing.